# create a reference table from two tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I transform my site to use Java EE and hibernate!

I have 3 tables:

```
like
id | table | idElement | userId

movie
movie_id | title | duration

videoGame
game_id | title | nbPlayer
```

and currently 2 class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="movie_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private int duration;

@Entity
@Table(name="videoGame")
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="game_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private int nbPlayer;
```

I do not know how to make my table "like" to link it to one of the two table and the correct id?

example:

```
table like:
+---+-------+-----------+-------+
|id | table | idElement | userId|
|1  | movie |  1        | 1     |
|1  | game  |  5        | 3     |
+---+-------+-----------+-------+
```

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no direct way to map your tables to hibernate (At least I am not aware of).

Using inheritance you can produce a similar effect. `Movie` and `Game` can be a subclass of another class (say `Likable`). So that you can use `Likable` class like below:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="like")
 public class Like {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="like_id")
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="likable_id", nullable=false)
   private Likable likable;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
   private User user;
}
```

`Likable` class will look like below:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "likable")  
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)   
public class Likable {  

   @Id  
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)     
   @Column(name = "id")  
   private int id;  

 }
```

`Movie` class:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="movie")
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")  
 public class Movie extends Likable {

     private String title;
    private int duration;
}
```

And `Game` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="videoGame")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Game extends Likable {

   private String title;
   private int nbPlayer;
}
```